# scrapy website with node.js and axios but resonse is encryption

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, axios, response

So I have this very simple node.js code trying to scrapy a website from data to make a api. But the reponse is node-sense or encrypted, can I do something?

My code

```
app.get('/p', (req, res) => {
axios.get('https://www.matchi.se/facilities/rck?date=2022-05-18&sport=5')
    .then((res) => {
        const html =res.data
        console.log(html);
    })

})

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`server is running on PORT ${PORT}`))
```

The response I get in the console:

```
▼�Kw�H�(��9�▼�X�%��☼�)Q�\▼����Dɯ��� D►�☺�↕]�9��Y�jvw9���        
sj=�'�K&"‼☺↕|Ȓ\�Mv�E☻������◄↓����7 O�I��↑/↕��☼1���'��$�↔�t֓- 
����rWWW٫bֲ�\�Z�殱t↕k1���͚��z��ֈW�Һ�♫˙�Ϥ)�?�5�I��JK��:��↓�!���
<w¶[��↔t�z�e�n���x�$J��♫sד獝�j�8�����¶��*���YF��_���Sh�J♂t���J�T��y� �H�EI]�3���t�/��D�↨��@�L��X6���↕�t\��a�K]�2�b�TF��§9e��@��e3�kY��H�j䐚Tc6◄p↔B↔�↑���K�r∟]���E∟��.���‼9�y1☼  D�↔DG��J��o
�♥�Ҭ☼♦_�u.��/����&�u§�l♀��↑�G¶�;��☼��%�Sl♠0��P �→��O�K*u)►��K�-�b�/�j�--=���.��H3��$♫�-!�:�¶�8q\�u♦i8�☻!,⌂�U���→Ϛ�.���#KeY` f�IR����3♫��r�J7U♂hg)���K��K�►����a�������������☺�6�I�♠�Ic�ں�⌂�
��▬�☺↕�→l=�IEy0♥$����M☺$��►☻�♣♣J�g��¶B27        Л�y-�iu� J@"�`շי��                                              �������J{O♠��{Եu���$�g"$E��t�Kx�֓}�]!
�0h]����☺⌂\X�Ch����J�R,�♂�2�Q↑�B�R�K�R¶��D��=tB�↔�2]∟��↑��▼w6�]S♂:���^�☻_2�l→=��⌂���<'^y�-♫♂X�ߏ�→B�X�ʫ��J�P-J�j�p�♫�Q��\�%��☻C���M�♥�↓☻↨C�)�'
♠↔X�����↔��~��?����m►�♠n��Qz��@�$i�"7�▲�j↨���-�
7��r�♦�E�{♥��0`f�#���gQ���}�w"��{♥��À��}☺�#��{♥܊n�▼`�揅bz�QY��♀7��↨�M����.��H�@��T↨V'�e��x[*
♥�_�♦��☺�0���d��:�☼→��q���‼MX���$�K�ۤ�ᅇ�oVp��_♥�L�♣�ZXv↔�ؔ↔X♦r��J�0�����↓7?T�9]�Ts�l   `z�&@|��{����§�▬|�ꖏw�����+��غ>����F��?�p;�[�o���޾e�%��%��&Xy�����H��饦�6^m��♂��+]_l�8�Ύ�e�▼�{���7{F
Vq����bqp♠sZ�A��z�¶▲����4.v��[w|�c��/8%��Q5P;♫V�,���*]9-∟�+���'Տ���FW��y�→׌�\�JoY��\9l�_�)�'↔��Wey{u���./�����a�♫¶m�♀w���+�3��S</)�|��U�;g˗+��wg�7/�+ҽ►4◄����]��)��O�~{���ק�{[�7K��m�i�5♂��
������N�gXcp8�~���→H=↑��z}���m��f�▲�僭�v��<��;�ʛ�����Nl�^e�[���4�7W��m������↕�W♠'e�b�/�V�L�޻�K���mk\0���♦;��P0H9Uw\�ѷk∟♦��f�b���l�J^�r�_l�↨�-�1=>��e�♦��♫��h��‼��↓d�RٸM�S�'�L�i��ʹ�v�����f�
.������FP��[Y�g♫T��9c�s6,�LܸB"~��c5�[♠��o�,���O=�mzÖ5���ze�)�▬����0 Hj'�7@��d6�Y�<���g!∟x�?<s��
��3↨�☺mǲ7m♂♦?�`f��`m�2�u�▲�§�~�u������F��◄5(☼m�x^�↑¶�a@�◄�d}}�☻���mm�PxR��l�a�9Ǎa⌂H�Vֆ▼j*J�=�ھVZ��e�o���ex♂⌂��|!�p�↔Z���Z♂��>?MFiJ��~%I�߯cD��i�b¶1����y�剘��31m4f2U�< �O�wc��♣��vR'm6 �♥xRU
�v�|�+���q�⌂��f�`�@j����_�♥ٶm�^��=C%��r�♥9��O.⌂◄��C���]��1�♣P����i�@�9�↓`��-�¡|�wp���t'��P♂�►��T����6↔♀�g↔CW↑W1��CZZ^^~�M-♦��KD♠Z�▬��P*pR���I���4�ԃ)♂_p[ݮ↓♠|���{�V��=6§♠�z�x☻%�4��r����:V�%
�z�ZH�q7]z�<�Y����z������N�J��ʇ�/f��BW��`��↑���¶�gS:h@☺�‼�R{�[���G�
�c�ح����⌂�i}}]�-�Oo�����O���k↔XW`~Q�����♠e�U�O-�∟_��►☼D��,,ei���►|{�>��%♫ֶ��(MkX�>♦j��(        ^�n♂��`☺v�#�yC^�g���r�6�☼�??����▲�rS8W'�P��;M�дď�(&0��\�↓�DFqS�{‼��K?e.��☼r     �Ka�
```

continues..

What I what is the html code from the page.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with puppeteer for this one.
Maybe their content is rendered on the frontend, and axios can't get it.

This piece of code will do the work to get data you need.

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')
  
const getData = async () => {
    try {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
        const page = await browser.newPage()
        await page.goto(
            'https://www.matchi.se/facilities/rck?date=2022-05-18&sport=5',
            { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' }
        )
        const data = await page.evaluate(
            () => document.querySelector('*').outerHTML
        )
        await browser.close()
        console.log(data)
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: thx but how do I make it a endpoint then? can I just wrapped i between this 
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    
})

Comment: Yes, you can use this function in the (req,res)=>{... function here} and then just serve the data in res.

Comment: Thanks I made it work now with express